# Local "document management" solution

Tags: windows, file-management

I am looking for a **local** document/content management system that will allow me to store a wide array of file types in with either **filters** or **tags** to search for.

Expanding on this, I would want a tool ideally capable of:

1. I would prefer to have **tags** to help me locate documents, as in tags such as `powershell` or `work`
2. I would prefer to have a system wherein I could create **filters** such as "Created on `Date Range` and `tagged`

Think of it like Calibre or other managers; applying filters and custom search queries help manage documents.

Thinking of tools such as [OpenDocMan](http://www.opendocman.com/document-management-system-pricing/), only a native **client-side** application- no web hosting wanted.

I am looking at [Krystal Document Management Solutions](https://www.krystaldms.in/comparison.php) Community Edition presently, to see if this meets my needs, however it seemingly fails:

1. Completely Web Browser based Application System
2. Accessible over the Internet, WAN or LAN
3. Subscription and Notification

Comment: For those wondering, I installed the `Community Edition` version of Krystal and it seems only capable of extracting data from the Enterprise Version (i.e. to export if you do not want to renew a license)

Comment: Also, FWIW, they do not need to be a "DMS" per-se, just having functionality above mentioned (tags, filters).

Answer (score 1):

So I will make a few assumptions here (since I cannot comment to request more information of your requirements): I am considering you wish only to have local access, in this I mean you do not wish to access these documents anywhere else, only in the computer in which you installed the application, and a local "network" access. Taking this into assumption I have a few recommendations for you:

1. **Evernote / Laverna:** why a note taking app for document management? Well, why not? Evernote has tags, content search, local installation, universal access, among other great features. I use Evernote for managing some documents for me. I included Laverna as a open source alternative but you can find more if you look. **Pros**: keeps documents in a database with small chance for corruption. Has universal/content search (including inside documents). Accessible anywhere. You can create special templates for specific types of documents. Integrates with a lot of other applications. No limits to file names. **Cons**: for the best experience the paid version is a must. Free version has some limitations on file sizes.
2. **File Explorer / FreeCommander / Other File Explorer replacement:** so these options do not create a database to store your files, however, some people just forget how powerful the average file explorer is and how there are many alternatives for this. **Pros**: already installed in your computer. No lessons curve. Free. Actively developed. **Cons**: limits on file names (character type and also length). Does not automatically organize your files (however there are other apps that can do this). Files are exposed to virus and corruption.
3. **LogicalDOC / OpenKM / Alfresco**: are great document managers. Regarding LogicalDOC, there is an option to install locally but also in a server. Has a community edition but if you need more power there are also paid flavours. I was going to put this one first on the list, but I seriously suggest you to take at least a look into Evernote.
4. **Virtualise**: I guess another way to go would be to create a local virtual server (with XAMPP as an example) and install a document manager that is supposed to be installed on a server, but will actually be local. I have never done this but seems like an alternative in the event the document manager that is "perfect for you" is one which requires installation into a server.

I hope I helped in some way.

Links:

https://www.logicaldoc.com/

https://www.openkm.com/

https://community.alfresco.com/docs/DOC-5792-download-and-install-alfresco

Answer (score 0):

For those searching for a more enterprise-driven, legal DMS system for user access and storage, I can recommend [bitfarm-Archive](https://www.bitfarm-archiv.com/) as a solution. Whilst it doesnot meet my needs as a service, it has the following:

1. Is a local housed solution;
2. Has user-level access to different databases;
3. Has filter and tag support, along with document naming conventions;
4. Has a server and client side GUI for management

The following is a screen of the "Administration" of the archives within the datbase:

[image: Basic Screen]

Installation was simple, and a right-click context menu added to copy and move files to the database.

Local solution is also **free** and runs under [GPL3 license](https://www.gnu.org/licenses/gpl-3.0.en.html).

Answer (score 0):

For others looking for a more basic approach, I came across the use of [XPlorer](https://www.xyplorer.com/), which has a **ton** of useful features.

The tool will cost me **$39.95-$79.95** depending on the edition if I was to go for it, however is a lifetime license.

Under the `Favourites` section of the tool I am able to allocate tags to files, which is a key feature I wanted to do for management of files.

Another core function this application has is the `Find Files` function, allowing me to search and refine filters by a plethora of search terms, as depicted below:

[image: Advanced Search]

Whilst this is not the *most* ideal tool (as I do plan on storing all data in an encrypted format), this tool meets all my requirements. I'll look for FOSS alternatives, though ;)

Comment: As far as I am aware, FreeCommanderXE does not have functionality for tagging and filters.